# ValueError: Type http_sys_content_t is invalid, must be a file or device type

Tags: httpd, centos7, selinux, rhel7

I need to set selinux permissions on a non-default httpd directory: `/www/virtualhosts/site01`, ect.

So I issue:

```
[mybox]# semanage fcontext -a -t http_sys_content_t "/www(/.*)?"
```

And get:

```
ValueError: Type http_sys_content_t is invalid, must be a file or device type
```

What needs to happen to configure selinux to work with my non-default httpd directory?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just need to fix your typo.

You entered:

```
http_sys_content_t
```

But it is correctly:

```
httpd_sys_content_t
```

Comment: What's the difference between  `httpd_sys_content_t` and `httpd_sys_rw_content_t`?    Should I give the same selinux permissions to the ssl certificate directory (again not the default)?

Comment: One is read only, one is read-write.

Comment: And, whenever possible, you should use the default directories. It will save you a lot of trouble later.

Comment: What is there a default ssl certificate directory in EL7?

Comment: The directories under `/etc/pki/tls`.